# PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type how is it possible?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

** pkg**

```
create or replace package pkg_raport_8h
is
        type rec_type_raport_8h is record
        (
                 sum_price number(9,3)
                ,sum_use   number (9,3)
        )
        ;

FUNCTION get_price_elec ( in_date_measurement_start IN elec_prod.date_measurement%type 
        ,in_date_measurement_end IN elec_prod.date_measurement%type)
         Return rec_type_raport_8h;
END pkg_raport_8h;



create or replace package body pkg_raport_8h is

function get_price_elec (in_date_measurement_start IN elec_prod.date_measurement%type, 
in_date_measurement_end IN elec_prod.date_measurement%type) Return rec_type_raport_8h is


v_sum  rec_type_raport_8h;



begin


select sum(price), sum(use_current)  into v_sum.sum_price, v_sum.sum_use from price_use_elec_prod puep 
where puep.date_measurement > in_date_measurement_start and puep.date_measurement < in_date_measurement_end;
return v_sum;


dbms_output.put_line(v_sum.sum_price);
dbms_output.put_line(v_sum.sum_use);


end get_price_elec;

end pkg_raport_8h;
```

when trying to use this feature

```
DECLARE
type rec_type_raport_8h is record
(
sum_price number
,sum_use number
)
;
v_sum1 rec_type_raport_8h;
BEGIN
v_sum1 := pkg_raport_8h.get_price_elec(to_date('18-NOV-2023 19:00:00'),to_date('18-NOV-2023 20:00:00'));
dbms_output.put_line(v_sum1.sum_price);
end;
```

receives error:
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 17, column 11:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
ORA-06550: line 17, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 - "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause: Usually a PL/SQL compilation error

I know that means it's the wrong data type. But how is it possible since I assigned it
the same data type in the declaration section as in the function?

Answer (score 4):

You define the `rec_type_raport_8h` data-type in the package and then you define it a second time in the anonymous PL/SQL block. Those two definitions may have the same attributes which each have the same data-types but the records are **NOT** the same data type.

Do **NOT** redefine the record and, instead, use the package record:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_sum1 pkg_raport_8h.rec_type_raport_8h;
BEGIN
  v_sum1 := pkg_raport_8h.get_price_elec(
              to_date(
                '18-NOV-2023 19:00:00',
                'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS',
                'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English'
              ),
              to_date(
                '18-NOV-2023 20:00:00',
                'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS',
                'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English'
              )
            );
  dbms_output.put_line(v_sum1.sum_price);
end;
/
```

*Note: If you are going to use `TO_DATE` then explicitly specify the format model rather than relying on an implicit format model defined in the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter (as any user can change their session parameters at any time, and if they do then your query will stop working).*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Krn2Yslp)

Answer (score 3):

These are two local types with the same name and structure. Oracle doesn't bother to check whether these two happen to look the same; for Oracle these are two different definitions, one local to package pkg_raport_8h, one local to the anonymous block that you use for calling the package function.

So, instead use the package definition in your calling block:

```
DECLARE
  v_sum1 pkg_raport_8h.rec_type_raport_8h;
BEGIN
  v_sum1 := pkg_raport_8h.get_price_elec(TIMESTAMP '2023-11-18 19:00:00',
                                         TIMESTAMP '2023-11-18 20:00:00');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_sum1.sum_price);
END;
```

I am using proper timestamp/datetime literals here, instead of converting strings with a conversion function. Moreover, your conversions may fail anytime, when session settings don't match the language you expect to be used with your query.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the previous answers, this is [documented behaviour](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/lnpls/plsql-packages.html#GUID-F82E9BF3-147B-4FB3-ABB9-1A94A781AA7D):

> **Note:** A PL/SQL composite type defined in a package specification is incompatible with an identically defined local or standalone type ....

[And](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-7C84EBD2-D0A5-4126-8EB7-FF9243EE5B47):

> A collection type defined in a package specification is incompatible with an identically defined local or standalone collection type.